# Dart how to filter list with self-relation using recursive function?

Tags: function, dart, recursion, where-clause

I'm trying to get a filtered list looking by the visible property, who needs be true.

```dart
class MyClass {
   bool visible;
   List<MyClass>? items;

  MyClass(this.visible, this.items);

  List<MyClass> getVisible() {
    List<MyClass> visibleItems = [];
    if (visible) {
      if (items != null) {
        for (MyClass child in items!) {
          visibleItems.addAll(child.getVisible());
        }
      }
      if (visible || items != null) {
        visibleItems.insert(0, this);
      }
    }
    return visibleItems;
  }
}
```

I have a list of my class `List<MyClass> myClass` and each item of the list can have child and a child item list can have another child too, so it's a class with self-relation.
In dart I tried to use map, but map could only filter the root path, and not check the property "visible == true" inside each child. I tried to write a recursive function, but without success.

Using where I could get the filtered list, but like the map function, only in the "root" of list and not filtering the child's.

I found a recursive function to filter the list

```dart
List<MyClass> getVisible() {
    List<MyClass> visibleItems = [];
    if (visible) {
      if (items != null) {
        for (MyClass child in items!) {
          visibleItems.addAll(child.getVisible());
        }
      }
      if (visible || items != null) {
        visibleItems.insert(0, this);
      }
    }
    return visibleItems;
  }
```

So I tried to test it to check if it will work as expected

```dart
  // Create my class items
  var item0 = MyClass(true, []);
  var item1 = MyClass(true, []);
  var item2 = MyClass(false, []);
  var item3 = MyClass(true, []);
  
  // Build tree structure
  item0.items = [item1, item2, item3];
  item1.items = [MyClass(true, [MyClass(true, []),MyClass(false, [])])];
  item2.items = [MyClass(true, [MyClass(true, [MyClass(false, []),MyClass(false, []),MyClass(true, [])])])];
  item3.items = [MyClass(true, []), MyClass(true, [])];
  
  // Create list of tree nodes
  List<MyClass> items = [item0, item1, item2, item3];

  // Get visible nodes for all nodes in the list
  List<MyClass> visibleItems = [];
  for (var node in items) {
    visibleItems.addAll(node.getVisible());
  }
```

This list is supposed to work dynamically, example, today the item1 has child, tomorrow the item1 child can have another child, so I don't want to do anything "hard-coded" and create a recursive function to return the list filtered the same way it was created. The recursive function that I tried to make it work, could filter the list, but returned the filtered list all in root path so breaking the self-relation and keeping the items in the relation not filtered...